# Why markdown syntax requires two spaces before \n to make a paragraph out of it?

Tags: javascript, markdown

I use [this](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) library to create markdown text editor in a webapp.

All formatting is intuitive, but the line breaks. I don't get, why i have to add double space and then `\n` to create line break? Is there other markdown => html js parser, which doesn't require this?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't require two spaces before a newline to make paragraphs. Paragraphs in Markdown are defined by *two consecutive* newlines (i.e. there must be a blank line in between the paragraphs). The "two spaces" syntax is for *line breaks*, i.e. `<br>` tags.

The reason for the two space rule for line breaks is shown in [the documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) (bold mine):

> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.
>
> The implication of the "one or more consecutive lines of text" rule is that Markdown supports "hard-wrapped" text paragraphs. This differs significantly from most other text-to-HTML formatters (including Movable Type’s "Convert Line Breaks" option) which translate every line break character in a paragraph into a `<br />` tag.
>
> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but **a simplistic "every line break is a `<br />`" rule wouldn’t work for Markdown. Markdown’s email-style [blockquoting](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote) and multi-paragraph [list items](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.**